# Is there a way to have a NSUInteger automatically display commas in iPhone?

Tags: iphone, nsuinteger

Like if I had 29993 would there be a way to automatically have it be displayed as 29,993?  Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want an [NSNumberFormatter](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSNumberFormatter_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/NSNumberFormatter).